# Inno Setup: Install .NET framework, reboot the system and continue installation

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to install some system prerequisites and after finalizing them restart the system, then it must continue the installation where I left off. The prerequisites are .NET framework and an update of Windows.

My `[Code]` section:

```pascal
const
  (*** Customize the following to your own name. ***)
  RunOnceName = 'My Program Setup restart';

  QuitMessageReboot = 'Os requisitos para a instalação do sistema não estão completos. Precisamos reiniciar seu computador para continuar a instalação do sistema.'#13#13'Depois de reiniciar o seu computador, o setup irá continuar a instalação após o primeiro login com uma conta administradora.';
  QuitMessageError = 'Error. Cannot continue.';

var
  Restarted: Boolean;
  ResultCode: Integer;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Restarted := ExpandConstant('{param:restart|0}') = '1';

  if not Restarted then begin
    Result := not RegValueExists(HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce', RunOnceName);
    if not Result then
      MsgBox(QuitMessageReboot, mbError, mb_Ok);
  end else
    Result := True;
end;

function DetectAndInstallPrerequisites: Boolean;
begin
  (*** Place your prerequisite detection and installation code below. ***)
  (*** Return False if missing prerequisites were detected but their installation failed, else return True. ***)

  if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe'), '/q /norestart', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    MsgBox(QuitMessageReboot + IntToStr(ResultCode) + '....',
      mbError, MB_OK);    
  end;

  Result := True;
end;

function Quote(const S: String): String;
begin
  Result := '"' + S + '"';
end;

function AddParam(const S, P, V: String): String;
begin
  if V <> '""' then
    Result := S + ' /' + P + '=' + V;
end;

function AddSimpleParam(const S, P: String): String;
begin
 Result := S + ' /' + P;
end;

procedure CreateRunOnceEntry;
var
  RunOnceData: String;
begin
  RunOnceData := Quote(ExpandConstant('{srcexe}')) + ' /restart=1';
  RunOnceData := AddParam(RunOnceData, 'LANG', ExpandConstant('{language}'));
  RunOnceData := AddParam(RunOnceData, 'DIR', Quote(WizardDirValue));
  RunOnceData := AddParam(RunOnceData, 'GROUP', Quote(WizardGroupValue));
  if WizardNoIcons then
    RunOnceData := AddSimpleParam(RunOnceData, 'NOICONS');
  RunOnceData := AddParam(RunOnceData, 'TYPE', Quote(WizardSetupType(False)));
  RunOnceData := AddParam(RunOnceData, 'COMPONENTS', Quote(WizardSelectedComponents(False)));
  RunOnceData := AddParam(RunOnceData, 'TASKS', Quote(WizardSelectedTasks(False)));

  (*** Place any custom user selection you want to remember below. ***)

  //<your code here>

  RegWriteStringValue(HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce', RunOnceName, RunOnceData);
end;

function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var
  ChecksumBefore, ChecksumAfter: String;
begin
  ChecksumBefore := MakePendingFileRenameOperationsChecksum;
  if DetectAndInstallPrerequisites then begin
    ChecksumAfter := MakePendingFileRenameOperationsChecksum;
    if ChecksumBefore <> ChecksumAfter then begin
      CreateRunOnceEntry;
      NeedsRestart := True;
      Result := QuitMessageReboot;
    end;
  end else
    Result := QuitMessageError;
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Restarted;
end;
```

The return is the variable `QuitMessageReboot` concatenated with the `ResultCode` that has the value `2`.

The `dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe` is installed by:

```
[Files]
;.Net Framework
Source: "Dependencias\.Net Framework\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; \
    Flags: deleteafterinstall
```

Comment: What is the question? You seem to have all the pieces done.

Comment: remove the parameters to be able to "see" the installation, but simply does not start and the error I mentioned in the post. The process enters if and generates the error code 2.

Comment: So which one of the three references to `QuitMessageReboot` are you seeing? Error code 2 is `FILE_NOT_FOUND`. Change the three uses of `QuitMessageReboot` so that you can tell which area of the code is causing the problem, and then you'll be able to ask a more specific question related to that area of code.

Comment: OK, so this fails, right? `Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe'` There's no code in the script you have shown us that creates/extracts/installs the `{tmp}\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe`. How is it created?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I'll edit the question to the part where I insert the file.

Comment: @KenWhite Greate idea.

Comment: @KenWhite Problem is in DetectAndInstallPrerequisites.

Comment: I found the error, the section of code is executed before the files are extracted in the folder "{temp}".I need to use a function that runs after extrais or files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name says, the [`PrepareToInstall` event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=PrepareToInstall) happens before the installation. The files are not installed yet. So the `Exec` obviously fails, as there's nothing to execute.

You can extract the `dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe` from the code using [`ExtractTemporaryFile` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extracttemporaryfile):

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "...\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
function DetectAndInstallPrerequisites: Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
  Success: Boolean;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe');

  WizardForm.PreparingLabel.Caption := 'Installing .NET framework...';
  WizardForm.PreparingLabel.Visible := True;
  try
    Success :=
      Exec(
        ExpandConstant('{tmp}\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe'), '/q /norestart', '',
        SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
  finally
    WizardForm.PreparingLabel.Caption := '';
    WizardForm.PreparingLabel.Visible := False;
  end;

  if not Success then
  ...
end;
```

Make sure you add the [`dontcopy` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=dontcopy) to the `[Files]` section entry.

Comment: My setup is incomplete, it does not install these requirements and does not ask to restart.

Comment: debugging the example code I found a problem...is not passed inside this if: 

if ChecksumBefore <> ChecksumAfter...

Comment: The test checks if there's a change by the dependencies installers (.NET framework in your case) that requires a restart. Maybe there's no change that requires the restart (maybe you have the framework installed already).

Comment: All right, perfect. I will now try on another machine that I'm sure that has nothing because it was formatted a few minutes. Thank you so far. How do I change the message of the installer? For I also tell which file is being currently installed.

Comment: While the installation is occurring, a message in the setup is ... I want to give feedback than installing this at the moment.